# Does it matter to do code in simple HTML rather than HTML 5 in PhoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova

I am trying to create simple app but it will give me headache to implement simple plugin like tabbar so i have created it using simple HTML.

So my question is if i create my app using simple HTML not even using HTML5 than does it make any difference? Does apple approve it?

Comment: apple rejects on the basis of the quality of the app and not on the language in which it is developed. Go ahead and use HTML :)

Answer (score 0):

No. It shouldn't matter.

HTML5 adds more features to HTML. So any browser which can render HTML5 can render HTML too. But why don't you use HTML5 new features. Anyway, if you stick into HTML. You misses out the ability to use any HTML5 based libraries.